# Consulta Para saber si un campo de tabla existe o no existe en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

No encuentro la forma de hacer la consulta para crear un campo en una tabla y una llave foránea en una base de datos PostgreSQL, pero verificando previamente que no exista.  En SQL server utilizo las siguientes pero no funcionan en PostgreSQL 9.1.

```
--- para un campo nuevo ------
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'workflowarea' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'wrko_area'
    )
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE workflowarea ADD wrko_area bigint NOT NULL;
    END
COMMIT TRANSACTION;




---- para llave foranea.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE name = 'workflowarea_ra_id_fk'
)
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE workflowarea DROP CONSTRAINT workflowarea_ra_id_fk; 
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

¿Cuál sería el equivalente en PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente consulta retornará `true/false`, utilizando la función [`EXISTS()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-subquery.html).

Traducción libre hecha por mi:

> **EXISTS()**:
>  El argumento de `EXISTS` es una sentencia `SELECT` cualquiera, o una sub-consulta. La sub-consulta es evaluada para determinar si retorna alguna fila. Si retorna por lo menos una fila, el resultado de `EXISTS` es `true`; si la sub-consulta no retorna fila alguna, el resultado es `false`

```
SELECT EXISTS(
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema='public' 
  and table_name='x' 
  and column_name='y')
```

dicho esto, puedes utilizar una sentencia de SQL dinámico para modificar tu tabla, por ejemplo:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  IF not EXISTS (SELECT column_name 
                 FROM information_schema.columns 
                 WHERE table_schema='public' 
                   and table_name='workflowarea' 
                   and column_name='wrko_area') THEN
    alter table workflowarea add column wrko_area bigint not null;
  else
    raise NOTICE 'El campo ya existe';
  END IF;
END
$$
```

Puedes utilizar esta misma técnica para determinar si no existe la llave foránea y agregarla.

Comment: Muchas Gracias funciona muy bien

Comment: Me alegra que te sirviera Manuel, considera [aceptar la respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, prueba con las siguientes sentencias SQL:

```
-- Para saber si existe una columna en una tabla
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='nombre_table' and column_name='nombre_columna';

-- Para saber si existe una llave en la tabla
SELECT * FROM pg_constraint WHERE conname = 'fk_modulo_controlador'
```

Espero de sea de ayuda :)

Comment: Hola si funciona pero es que el asunto es como ponerle una condicion en postgress asi como en sql server es que en postgress no me ejecuta con un if not exists

Answer (score 0):

A partir de postgres 9.6 es posible usar "IF NOT EXISTS" para la creación de columnas:

```
ALTER TABLE workflowarea ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS wrko_area bigint not null;
```

Para las FK no existe esa comodidad, pero puedes eliminarla IF EXISTS y crearla de nuevo

```
ALTER TABLE workflowarea DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS fk_modulo_controlador;
ALTER TABLE workflowarea ADD CONSTRAINT fk_modulo_controlador ...;
```